# Using complex analysis to find the Inverse Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I have been reviewing for my comprehensive graduation exam where I have been solving the Inverse Laplace transform via complex analysis. Consider 
$$
H(s) = \frac{s^2 - s + 1}{(s + 1)^2}
$$
Then we have two poles at $s = -1$.
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{s^2 - s + 1}{(s + 1)^2}e^{st}ds = \sum\text{Res}(F(s)e^{st})
$$
I get 
$$
\lim_{s\to -1}[2s - 1 + t(s^2 - s + 1)]e^{st} = -3e^{-t} + 3te^{-t}
$$
but if I solve the problem by partial fractions and tables, I also pick up Dirac delta; that is, the solution should be
$$
\delta(t) -3e^{-t} + 3te^{-t}
$$
How did I lose a Dirac delta function?

Comment: The obvious thing to test is how to get the Dirac delta by itself---whose Laplace transform is just a constant---via contour integration.

Comment: @Semiclassical that would mean I would need to have $\lim_{s\to 0}1\cdot e^{st}$ but I don't see how I pull that out of computing the direct residue with out long division or partial fractions.

Comment: You can just do the long division, even when doing the inverse transform by contour integration. You get $H(s) = 1-\frac{3s}{(s+1)^2}$. The term $1$ is where the Dirac delta is coming from, although I am not sure how to explain why its inverse Laplace transform is actually the Dirac delta from within the residue framework.

Comment: @Ian You can, in a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much a proof as a demonstration. We'll take the Bromwich integral and stick a constant 1 in it. We have the Inverse Laplace transform as

$$
F(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma-i \infty}^{\gamma+i \infty} e^{st} f(s) ds
$$

where $\gamma$ is a real number that must be chosen so that all the poles of $f(s)$ lie to the left of the vertical contour it defines.

Set $f(s)=1$, and we can take $\gamma=0$ for convenience since our function has no poles. I'll introduce a limit in the integration limits, $p$. You'll then have

$$
F(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-i p}^{+i p} e^{st} ds \\
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \left. \frac{e^{st}}{t} \right|_{-ip}^{ip} \\
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}  \left( \frac{e^{ipt}-e^{-ipt}}{t} \right) \\
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i t} \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}  2 i \sin(pt) \\
= \lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\sin pt}{\pi t}
$$

Now one of the "definitions" of the Dirac-delta function as a "limit" is
$$
\lim_{e \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\pi x} \sin \left( \frac{x}{e} \right)
$$

Which is precisely our result, if you set $e=1/p$. So if you assume the integral makes sense, the inverse Laplace transform of 1 should be the Dirac delta "function".

Comment: If you see in the comments, I ask how can this be done directly without having to resort to division or partial fractions. A solution with division/partial fractions should be the same as one without since the problem is identical except for the make representation. With the original problem, we have no isolated one. There has to be a way to get the correct answer from $\frac{s^2 - s + 1}{(s+1)^2}$ otherwise $1 - \frac{3s}{(s+1)^2}$ wouldn't be equivalent to $\frac{s^2 - s + 1}{(s+1)^2}$.